# What if there is a polynomial-time algorithm to minimize NFA?

Tags: complexity-theory, automata, space-complexity

Knowing that NFA-minimization has been proven to be P-SPACE complete, what if there is a polynomial-time algorithm to minimize NFA? Does that imply that P = PSPACE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If any PSPACE-complete problem is proved to be in P, then that proves that P = PSPACE, i.e., every problem in PSPACE can be solved in polynomial time.

Why?  Suppose we have a polynomial time algorithm for NFA minimization.  Since NFA minimization is PSPACE-complete, any other problem in PSPACE can be solved by reducing the problem to NFA minimization, then applying the polynomial-time algorithm for NFA minimization.  The definition of PSPACE-complete ensures that the reduction step will complete in polynomial time, so solving that problem can be done in polynomial time.